# click on parent except one of its child - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my fiddle [**link**](https://jsfiddle.net/aidadev/Lg4apemo/8/).

I want to do some actions on clicking the parent box, except its one child with class `.notClickableCol`. I used `:not()`, but currently it is not working.

It is working when this text ("Not Clickable") is without `<span>` tag.

Any ideas?

HTML/CSS/Jquery:

```js
jQuery(".row").on('click', ':not(.notClickableCol)', function() {
  alert('success');
});
```

```css
.row {
  margin-bottom:15px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
}
.row {
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  text-align:center;
  color:#fff;
  font-family:Arial;
  font-weight:bold;
  margin-right:10px;
  background:#ff6777;
  margin-left:50px;
}
.clickableCol {
  display:block;
  cursor:pointer;
  margin-top:45px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  color:#000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <span class="clickableCol">Clickable</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <span class="notClickableCol">Not Clickable</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <span class="clickableCol">Clickable</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <span class="notClickableCol">Not Clickable</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <span class="clickableCol">Clickable</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <span class="notClickableCol">Not Clickable</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.row :not(.notClickableCol)` -> `$(".row :not(.notClickableCol)").on('click', function () {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector is too broad. I'd use `.col` instead of `.row`:

```
jQuery(".col :not(.notClickableCol)").on("click", function () {
    alert('success');
});
```

Here's [a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nfbn2po2/2/).

---

You could also just just `clickableCol` and drop the `.not()` all together:

```
jQuery(".clickableCol").on("click", function() {
  alert('success');
});
```

[Here's another working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/3caxkh61/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like following.

```
jQuery(".row").click(function (e) {
    if (!$(e.target).hasClass('notClickableCol')) {
        alert('success');
    }
});
```

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg4apemo/9/)**

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you rather focus on the clickable element? like this:

```
 jQuery(".row").on('click', '.clickableCol', function () {
    alert('success');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of excluding only the notclickablecol, you can tell it to only register when it has the class clickablecol using the has selector:

```
/* For a clickable col inside this row, not every clickableCol
that might be in another table */
jQuery(".row").on('click', ':has(.clickableCol)', function () {
    alert('success');
});
```

You could just use an onclick event on the .clickableCol class, but this isn't nice because you might want another action when you click another col with this class.

Answer (score 0):

Should describe not span with defined class ...

```
jQuery(".row").on('click', 'span:not(.notClickableCol)', function() {
  alert('success');
});
```